# modifying the string literal

Tags: pointers, segmentation-fault, string-literals

Why does this code is successful in changing the string literal:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char w[] = "hello";
    char *ptr;
    ptr = w;
    printf("\nw = %p\n", w);
    printf("ptr = %p\n", ptr);

    printf("%s\n", ptr);
    *(ptr + 1) = 'r';
    printf("%s\n", ptr);
}
```

while this does not (gives segmentation fault error):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char w[] = "hello";
    char *ptr = "hello";
    printf("\nw = %p\n", w);
    printf("ptr = %p\n", ptr);

    printf("%s\n", ptr);
    *(ptr + 1) = 'r';
    printf("%s\n", ptr);
}
```

I was expecting both should work

Answer (score 0):

> Why does this code is successful in changing the string literal:

It *does not* change the string literal. It uses a string literal to *initialize* a modifiable array `w` of characters, and then changes that array.

If you look at the disassembly of the program, you would see something like this:

```
   0x0000000000001149 <+0>:     push   %rbp
   0x000000000000114a <+1>:     mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x000000000000114d <+4>:     sub    $0x10,%rsp
   0x0000000000001151 <+8>:     movl   $0x6c6c6568,-0xe(%rbp)
   0x0000000000001158 <+15>:    movw   $0x6f,-0xa(%rbp)
...
```

- The instruction at `+4` reserves 16 bytes of writable space on the stack.
- The instructions at `+8` and `+15` initialize that space with `h` (`0x68`), `e` (`0x65`), ..., `o` (`0x6f`) literal (in reverse order here because `x86_64` is little-endian).
- The address `-0xe($rbp)` is then used as the value of `ptr`.

Compare this to your other program, after removing the `w` from it (which is printed but not used):

```
   0x0000000000001149 <+0>:     push   %rbp
   0x000000000000114a <+1>:     mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x000000000000114d <+4>:     sub    $0x10,%rsp
   0x0000000000001151 <+8>:     lea    0xeac(%rip),%rax        # 0x2004
```

Here the address of the *string literal* (`0x2004` here) is loaded into the register and used as the value of `ptr`.